# skip elements from xml document

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document in which I want to extract every 10 elements. I used this code to extract the last 10 elements and then skip the 10 ones  and get older ones , i used this code but it replace the older the first list by another one containing the oldest 10 by skiping the last 10 elements, what i want is to get the last 10 elements and when the user press a button he will get the older list and another 10 older elements before them:

```
slideView.ItemsSource = 
    (from channel in xmlItems.Descendants("album")     
     orderby (int)channel.Element("catid") descending 
     select new onair
     {
         title = (string)channel.Element("name"),
         photo = (string)channel.Element("picture")
     }).Skip(10).Take(10);
```

any ideas please??

Answer (score 0):

Not so far, you just need to create some pagination in Linq (adapt this code to your case)

```
    public IEnumerable<onair> GetItems(int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        return (from channel in xmlItems.Descendants("album")
                orderby (int)channel.Element("catid") descending
                select new onair
                {
                    title = (string)channel.Element("name"),
                    photo = (string)channel.Element("picture")
                }).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    }
...

slideView.ItemsSource = GetItems(2,10):
```